# Django OAuth Toolkit: could not import ext.rest_framework

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

I am trying to set up OAuth2 authentication system for my Django REST API (using DjangoRestFramework and Django-Oauth-Toolkit).
I wrote everything according to the official documentation, but the system gives error "could not import ext.rest_framework"

Here is my setting.py file:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # this is the list of available scopes
    'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope', 'groups': 'Access to your groups'}
}


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I checked the source code for `oauth2_provider`. Apparently they changed the structure, but did not update the tutorial on their website. So, `oauth2_provider.ext` package does not exist anymore, you should use `oauth2_provider.contrib` instead. That is, the following code works fine:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```